# Share Qt widget between plugins

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, compiler-errors

I have a GUI program that has the main program, plugin A, and plugin B which is dependent on plugin A existing since plugin B uses widgets contained in plugin A.  The program and plugins are written using Qt.  I am able to compile the main program and plugin A just fine.

The current problem I'm facing is a compile error in plugin B saying: `'ui_MyWidget.h' file not found`.  The classes (*.h *.cpp and *.ui) for MyWidget are located in plugin A.  I think I can resolve this issue by including the `UI_DIR` folder in plugin A to the `INCLUDEPATH` in plugin B, but that doesn't seem like a graceful solution.

What I am attempting to do to include plugin A within plugin B may be too simple, but I am trying this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD \
    $$PWD/ui \
    $$PWD/sources

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../plugins/debug -lPluginAd
} else {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../plugins -lPluginA
}
```

Is there a special way to reuse widgets between plugins that I am unaware of?

Comment: Any way you can put the common widgets in a 3rd plugin?

Comment: Are you suggesting have plugin A, plugin B, then plugin C which contains the shared widgets?  I still don't see how that would get me any further than I currently am.

Comment: If A contains some widgets that B needs that are not also directly dependent on B, they could go in C.  And the reverse situation too.  So then A is dependent on C and possibly B, and B is dependent on C and possibly A.
But that depends really upon what your exact dependency problem is as you don't describe it fully.